# NgxEchartsModule: tooltip can't be used to index type 'TopLevelFormatterParams'

Tags: angular, echarts

I am having some troubles to get tooltip functionality to work with angular echarts, this is my setup:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getEntries().subscribe(data => {
      this.entries = data;

      const date_times: string[] = this.entries.map(e => e.datetime);
      const values: number[] = this.entries.map(e => e.value);

      this.chartOption = {
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          data: date_times,
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'value',
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: 'axis',
          axisPointer: {
            type: 'shadow',
          },
          formatter: (params) => {
          return params[0].seriesName;
        }
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: values,
            type: 'line',
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  }
```

But I get error

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression
> of type '0' can't be used to index type 'TopLevelFormatterParams'.
> Property '0' does not exist on type 'TopLevelFormatterParams'.
>
> 41           return params[0].seriesName;

Anyone here who knows how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this fixed the problem even though it is quite ugly (adapted from here: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/14723):

```
import { TooltipComponentOption } from 'echarts/components'

type Unified<T> = Exclude<T, T[]>
type TooltipFormatterCallback = Exclude<NonNullable<TooltipComponentOption['formatter']>, string>
// single and multiple params
type TooltipFormatterParams = Parameters<TooltipFormatterCallback>[0]
// single params
type SingleTooltipFormatterParams = Unified<TooltipFormatterParams>

const formatter0: TooltipFormatterCallback = (params: TooltipFormatterParams) => {
  if (Array.isArray(params)) {
    return params[0].data.toString() || 'no value';
  }
  return params.data.toString() || '';
}

...

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getEntries().subscribe(data => {
      this.entries = data;

      const date_times: string[] = this.entries.map(e => e.datetime);
      const values: number[] = this.entries.map(e => e.value);

      this.chartOption = {
        xAxis: {
          type: 'category',
          data: date_times,
        },
        yAxis: {
          type: 'value',
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: formatter0
        },
        series: [
          {
            data: values,
            type: 'line',
          },
        ],
      };
    });
  }
```